# diagonal parallax with scrollto nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollto, parallax

I'm trying to create a site that has a parallax type effect with scrollTo navigation control.

Similar to http://www.nike.com/jumpman23/aj2012/ however I only need to scroll on left and right (up & down). I can do horizontal and vertical parallax, and scrollTo I  just cant get the diagonal parallax working (with mouse scroll)

I've currently got it working using scrollTo however this disables the user being able to scroll with the mouse. I'm creating a dynamic one page site so some times a pages content may be longer then other areas so the user will need to scroll down, once they reach the end of this content the parallax effect kicks in.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this? Or point me in the right direction.

Comment: I answer questions like this quite frequently. You need to capture the `mousewheel` event. From here, you should have two variables. One outside of the function that you can update, and then refer to after the mousewheel movement has ended. Another one, inside the function, that you can compare against, `if var b > var a` then we're scrolling down. `if var a > var b` then we're scrolling up. Inside of here, you can use your scroll method and this will work as intended. Since you provided no code, I won't either. Best of luck.